# Editing csv files through PHP

Tags: php

I am making a quiz on a webpage for my media class. I am new to programming.  I need to learn how to edit my data csv file to make it more useful. Currently, when I look at my csv file, I only get four columns of numbers (the results of the quiz). I need to add two columns, one that includes a timestamp and one that shows the IP address of the person that filled out the quiz.

Part of My PHP looks like this:

```
    $csv_filehandle = fopen("/var/www/html/data/quiz.csv",'a');
    fputcsv($csv_filehandle,array($summer,$spring,$fall,$winter));
    fclose ($csv_filehandle);

    $visit_id = uniqid('',TRUE);

    $all_my_variables = array(
        'timestamp' => $current_timestamp,
        'user_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'summer' => $summer,
        'spring' => $spring,
        'fall' => $fall,
        'winter' => $winter,
    );

    $json_filehandle = fopen("/var/www/html/data/$visit_id.json",'w');
    fwrite($json_filehandle,json_encode($all_my_variables));
    fclose($json_filehandle);




    $current_hour = date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    $current_timestamp = date(DATE_RFC822);
```

Where/how do I add these columns so that they show up on my csv file?
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of rearranging this chunk of code and posting it for multiple different questions, you should just explain straight out what you're attempting to do. my suggestion: ditch the CSV stuff and go straight to a database.

Comment: +1 for making progress, posting nice code blocks and expressing humility.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a flat-file database with PHP.  Your immediate options:

**Enrich your use of a text file:**

- http://www.designdetector.com/archives/04/10/FlatFileDatabaseDemo.php
- http://www.xentrik.net/php/flatfile.php

**Upscale to a minimal database.**
The preferred tool is SQLite:

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/php-tutorial-creating-and-modifying-sqlite-databases
- http://fwebde.com/php/sqlite-php/

Answer (score 0):

This adds two columns at the end, timestamp and IP.

```
fputcsv( $csv_filehandle,
        array($summer,
            $spring,
            $fall,
            $winter, 
            time(), 
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) 
);
```